# Android: How to pass a value from an AppWidgetProvider to a service?

Tags: android, configuration, widget

I would like to pass a value from the AppWidgetProvider to a service. How can I do that? This value is taken from the widget configuration. If this value changes (by going to the configuration again), how do I pass it back to the service? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that?

Call `startService()` and package your value as an extra on the `Intent`.